Dynamic loading materials color from content browser Unreal Engine 5
I have a material. In content browser I have a set of imported png files (color_1, color_2, color_3...). I need to apply these assets to base color input one after another every second. Is it possible to implement this using nodes in the material editor?
Here i need to use only Base color node. The texture sample heve to change textures material editor
ex1
ex2
ex3
